# String Only For oddly formatted password

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Ok, I have a lot of passwords that are oddly formatted that needs to be passed a raw string. I know to use the ' to force any $ from activating. However, some of these passwords have ' inside of them. So, How would I go about raw stringing them data? Example of one of the passwords I am struggling with:

```
|4255a7]'KbuSkaiC$^&#{/d}nV41L8#*B?,3pevv
```

Notice the $^ This will trigger "userpassword" to appear inside the script. If I use a ' at the front, it stops at the ' before the K. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd escape special characters with a backtick. However for single quote just double it up.

```
'|4255a7]''KbuSkaiC$^&#{/d}nV41L8#*B?,3pevv'
```

Output

```
|4255a7]'KbuSkaiC$^&#{/d}nV41L8#*B?,3pevv
```

Note that if you're taking input from a user say with `Read-Host` - they do not need to escape it.

```
$var = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Password"
Enter Password: |4255a7]'KbuSkaiC$^&#{/d}nV41L8#*B?,3pevv

$var
|4255a7]'KbuSkaiC$^&#{/d}nV41L8#*B?,3pevv
```